# How to parse openssl certificate output into hostname and verification codes?

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, scripting, certificates

I have this shell code that reads lines of host names from input file, performs an `openssl` command to print ssl certificate info, and outputs the results in the terminal.

```
while read x; 
do
echo $x;
echo | openssl s_client -servername "$x" -connect "$x":443 -CApath etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt 2>/dev/null;
done <mylist.txt
```

This is an example output:

```
example.com
CONNECTED(00000003)
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=*.vhs.ir
   i:/CN=*.vhs.ir
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/CN=*.example.com
issuer=/CN=*.example.com
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1444 bytes and written 325 bytes
Verification error: certificate has expired
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: 03FC884879FB1BC4E471721134E9FE75E08C0C36047D9A0C4570FE6EABA77F8C
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 38EE0A6AE709E2DCD11B5C47C19713B78FE3959B42498699D604940A9B62DD64D3C3E03918BF25FD5CECA7403EAE590E
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 10800 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - a4 da 49 66 62 ff aa e7-be bd 76 58 0e d5 fb 45   ..Ifb.....vX...E
    0010 - d8 44 c8 2e b1 46 e9 22-6e eb e6 e3 0f eb 8f dc   .D...F."n.......
    0020 - 8a 57 16 a0 1b 16 36 33-87 2b a3 38 cc 1b 4e c0   .W....63.+.8..N.
    0030 - f4 3c 9e d7 82 1d 34 ce-b2 bb 18 95 43 33 74 b7   .<....4.....C3t.
    0040 - 24 65 7d 66 94 1e 4f e2-ff 19 e4 71 af bb 51 01   $e}f..O....q..Q.
    0050 - f1 fd 55 26 0d 65 39 aa-ef b2 d4 12 84 29 57 96   ..U&.e9......)W.
    0060 - 01 2b ae 36 c0 82 f6 e3-4e f9 3e 3b 6d 40 8f ae   .+.6....N.>;m@..
    0070 - 9a f0 da 95 c2 61 90 42-38 f6 4f 43 78 a5 f4 a5   .....a.B8.OCx...
    0080 - 16 27 c8 23 81 fe 98 59-52 87 c1 46 71 3a 34 5d   .'.#...YR..Fq:4]
    0090 - 6a 1b eb a8 4d 57 19 ea-0b 47 5e 39 8e 07 23 16   j...MW...G^9..#.
    00a0 - 34 14 f4 0f 0e 4e 13 55-f8 76 10 64 6c 52 e6 c5   4....N.U.v.dlR..
    00b0 - 17 4b 5d 11 89 35 4e ae-97 f1 b7 36 f8 c4 03 56   .K]..5N....6...V

    Start Time: 1552057179
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 10 (certificate has expired)
    Extended master secret: no
```

I want to output the results in a file, each host (`x`) separated by comma, its verification result (which is the text after `Verify return code:`).

I tried to add the line:
`| grep "Verify return code:"` after the command in the shell script but did not work.

How can I make the shell script print the output as: x,(what comes after `"Verify return code:"`) ?

**Example:**

> example.com,10 (certificate has expired)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
while read -r x
do
    vreturn=$(echo | openssl s_client -servername "$x" -connect "$x":443 -CApath etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt 2>/dev/null | awk -F\: '$1 ~ "Verify return code"{print $2}')
    echo "${x},$vreturn"
done <mylist.txt
```

This will use `:` as a field separator and set the `vreturn` variable to the second field of any line containing `Verify return code` in it's first line.

Also note `;` is not required at the end of each line.

I've added the `-r` option to your `read` command, mostly out of habit but this will prevent any backslashes that may be in your host names (unlikely) from being interpreted as escape characters.

Comment: For some reason, it does not loop over all the items in the file.

Comment: I've re-added the `echo` before the `openssl` command.  Otherwise it appears to wait for keyboard input before moving on